# Windows Phone 8 => Download DLL during runtime?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

i am currently developing a Windows Phone Project consisting of multiples libraries where i will sometime need to update the different assemblies by downloading a DLL file over the internet.

Is it possible to load DLL on runtime on Windows Phone 8 and accomplish the goal described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not allowed. All binaries that run on the phone must be signed by MSFT as part of their App Ingestion process via submittal to the Windows Phone App Store.

If you need dynamic updating, you might consider using a Web App, which allows you to pull content (not binaries) from a web source.

Comment: Okay, i guess my only option then would be to use some scripting language dynamically loaded and parsed on the C# side. Edit: No remote content needed, it is actually a library to be used by other developers in their  Windows Phone Application, i want to make it as pain-free as possible.