# How to load assembly dynamically by Assembly.Load in Windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, .net-assembly, dllimport

Now I have a problem, I want to load assembly dynamically depend on the platform(x86,ARM). I create a conditional compilation symbol _M_ARM to distinguish between x86 and ARM.

So I use **System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(@"MP3/ARM/Mp3EncLib.dll")**, but occur an exception  that Assembly.LoadFrom is not support on Windows Phone.

So I use another method **System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(@"MP3/ARM/Mp3EncLib.dll")**, but it throw an exception which is

> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'MP3/ARM/Mp3EncLib.dll, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one
>   of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
#if _M_ARM
    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(@"MP3/ARM/Mp3EncLib.dll");
#else 
    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(@"MP3/X86/Mp3EncLib.dll");
#endif
}
```

This is my solution
[image]

Anybody know how to use the method. Or better way

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846018/windows-phone-8-download-dll-during-runtime

Comment: @gretro, I'm not download dll file from the internet, the dll files just included in the project.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you must fully qualify the assembly like `SomeCompany.SomeNamespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`.

Answer (score 0):

From everything I have read on the internet, this is still not possible even in UWP.

I have created a feature request here: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/18145291-dynamically-load-assembly

It would be appreciated if you vote this feature up. Meantime, I think the only answer is the answer mentioned above which only really works in the scenario where you are able to put the DLL in the AppX package at deployment time.